# Action Bar Title Disappearing When Setting Image

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-imageview

I am trying to set Image into action bar, I am using CircularImagView to do that.

(ScaleType.FIT_END does not work for CircularImageView but i have also tried ImageView Same result even when ScaleType.FIT_END is applied).

It works fine for a larger screen phone but the title disappears for a less wide phone.

for example title shows fine for a wide phone like nexas 5x

[image: nexas 5x]

But does not show up in a narrow device like my physical phone.

[image: side by side comparison]

here is the code i am using to set the image

```
             try {
                // setting the image in the actionbar
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().getDisplayOptions()
                        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
                CircleImageView imageView = new CircleImageView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
                //imageView.setScaleType(CircleImageView.ScaleType.FIT_END);
                //imageView.setForegroundGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(imageView);
                // setting the image in actionbar ends here
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Even the ScaleType.FIT_END or Gravity.RIGHT does not help

(ScaleType.FIT_END does not work for CircularImageView but i have also tried ImageView Same result even when ScaleType.FIT_END is applied).

bitmap is global variable and i am setting it in onCreate, to make things less complicated i didn't included that.

What might be the solution for this ?

Comment: Try taking low resolution image , also fix the width and height of circular image view.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please don't abuse bold formatting

Comment: got it, thanks for the info

Comment: Manohar Reddy

i solved it by following your suggestion

Comment: by adding this                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

Comment: can you make that an answer so i can choose it as answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the suggestion of Manohar Reddy
I have Created a LinearLayout to create a LayoutParam, have set width and height on that and have set that layout param to the imageview which fixed the issue

```
    try {
                    // setting the image in the actionbar
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(getSupportActionBar().getDisplayOptions()
                            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
                    CircleImageView imageView = new CircleImageView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(imageView);
                    // setting the image in actionbar ends here
     } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

had to create a new layout param cause there no imageview in activity xml so can't get the params. Hope this helps someone.